# Python String/Argument Manipulation

Tags: python, string, syntax, syntax-error, user-input

I have a function that has a `name1` value obtained through user input via `sys.argv.pop()` that dictates which parameter within `myconfig.py` to use. As someone relatively new to python I was wondering what the proper way to go about doing this was, so that I would be given access to the desired data properly.

when completed I'd like the argument to function as : `myconfig.Oink['lower_bound']` or `myconfig.Woof['lower_bound']`

```
> self.do_x(id, myconfig."name1".format(name1)['lower_bound'],
> myconfig."name1".format(name1)['upper_bound'])
>                                                  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
__________________________________________________________________

> myconfig.py
> 
> Oink = dict(lower_bound = 874,upper_bound = 1983,) 

> Woof = dict(lower_bound = 1,upper_bound = 984,)
```

Comment: Ideally, you should change `myconfig` to be a dict rather than an object, because dicts are made for looking up values by name: `myconfig[name1]['lower_bound']`. If you can't do that for some reason, you _can_ use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function, like `getattr(myconfig, name1)['lower_bound']`. But, as you can see, this is a lot clunkier—when you need `getattr`, that's a good sign that you probably wanted a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
name1 = sys.argv.pop()

# ...

values = getattr(myconfig, name1)
self.do_x(values['lower_bound'], values['upper_bound'])
```

Please note that `getattr` is case sensitive, this means that while `getattr(myconfig, 'Oink')` will yield the correct value, `getattr(myconfig, 'oink')` will raise an `AttributeError`

---

If you want to handle invalid values, you can use [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
if not hasattr(myconfig, name1):
    raise ValueError('Invalid value {}'.format(name1))

values = getattr(myconfig, name1)
self.do_x(values['lower_bound'], values['upper_bound'])
```

---

If instead of raising a `ValueError` you want to use a default value, you can use the `default` keyword argument for `getattr`:

```
default = dict(lower_bound=20, upper_bound=50)
values = getattr(myconfig, name1, default=default)
self.do_x(values['lower_bound'], values['upper_bound'])
```